# How to edit the UI of the Opportunity stages?

Tags: opportunity, page-layout

[image]

An opportunity record can go from 'Out for signature' to 'Closed' Or to 'Starting at Risk' on the Opportunity detail page. The UI does not do a good job in showing that so I would ideally like to show the stages branching out from 'Out for signature' to either 'Closed' or 'Starting at Risk' which would be some UI change. Where to make that change?  I tried looking at the Opportunity page layout but nothing there allows me to edit that.

Comment: did you try to reorder the Stage picklist?

Comment: That would just change the order of the stages. But I am wanting to make a UI change whereby the 'Closed' & 'Starting at Risk' stages are on top of one another so it is obvious that a stage can go to either one of them.

Comment: You cannot modify the standard Path Component, but have you taken a look at [this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=path_final_status.htm&type=5#path_final_status)? It helps you to group the final stage.

Comment: I am not sure if I got your point. Would you like also 'Starting at Risk' be a closed Stage? If yes, the doc from @JayantDas answered your question

Comment: Yes it did. Thank You. The concept of grouping stages was new to me. Cheers! @m Peixoto